# parseFloat Doesn't Give Exact Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsefloat

I am working on a project which is require 'tip box' calculation system. As you see in the code snippet, it doesn't work as I expected. How can I solve this problem?

```js
$("select[name='tip']").on('change',function(){
    var thiz = $(this);
    var content_credit = parseFloat($("#f_content_credit").text());
    var total_balance = parseFloat($("#f_total_balance").text());
    var tip = parseFloat(thiz.val());

    console.log(total_balance+"-"+content_credit+"-"+tip);
    
    $("#f_after_confirm").text(total_balance-content_credit-tip);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
            <td> <strong>Total Balance</strong> </td>
            <td id='f_total_balance'> 45.67 </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
            <td> <strong>Credit</strong> </td>
            <td id='f_content_credit'> 10.20 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <strong>TIP BOX</strong></td>
            <td> 
                <select name="tip" class='form-control'>
                    <option value="0" selected>0 Kredi</option>
                    <option value="0.10">0.1 credit</option>
                    <option value="0.20">0.2 credit | not working</option>
                    <option value="0.30">0.3 credit</option>
                    <option value="0.80">0.8 credit</option>
                    <option value="1.20">1.2 credit | not working</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <strong>After Confirm Calculation</strong> <br><small>Total Balance - Credit - Tip</small> </td>
            <td id='f_after_confirm'> 35.47 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Welcome to the world of floating point maths! Note that `parseFloat()` is a native JS method. It has nothing at all to do with jQuery

Comment: @Alexis I'm almost tempted to close as a dupe of that

Comment: Looks like [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) is the best option for you, as it's well suited for currency figures.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've flagged this as duplicate too

Comment: @Alexis I wouldn't say it's technically a dupe as OP is asking 'How can I fix this', not 'Why does it happen'

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You're right, don't know then. Problem is the same, but not same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this, use `toFixed()` for decimal point.

```js
$("select[name='tip']").on('change',function(){
    var thiz = $(this);
    var content_credit = parseFloat($("#f_content_credit").text()).toFixed(2);
    var total_balance = parseFloat($("#f_total_balance").text()).toFixed(2);
    var tip = parseFloat(thiz.val()).toFixed(2);

    console.log(total_balance+"-"+content_credit+"-"+tip);
    
    $("#f_after_confirm").text(parseFloat(total_balance-content_credit-tip).toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
            <td> <strong>Total Balance</strong> </td>
            <td id='f_total_balance'> 45.67 </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
            <td> <strong>Credit</strong> </td>
            <td id='f_content_credit'> 10.20 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <strong>TIP BOX</strong></td>
            <td> 
                <select name="tip" class='form-control'>
                    <option value="0" selected>0 Kredi</option>
                    <option value="0.10">0.1 credit</option>
                    <option value="0.20">0.2 credit | not working</option>
                    <option value="0.30">0.3 credit</option>
                    <option value="0.80">0.8 credit</option>
                    <option value="1.20">1.2 credit | not working</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <strong>After Confirm Calculation</strong> <br><small>Total Balance - Credit - Tip</small> </td>
            <td id='f_after_confirm'> 35.47 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The `0.2` and `1.2` options still show values which the OP is not expecting. You need to call `toFixed()` on the value you place in the `text()` of `#f_after_confirm`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes agree with you thanks for notice this, now changed.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to inconsistencies in floating point calculations. You can read more about that at the link @Alexis mentioned in the comments, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

To fix your actual issue you can call `toFixed()` on the final summed value to format it to the required number of decimal places. Try this:

```js
$("select[name='tip']").on('change', function() {
  var thiz = $(this);
  var content_credit = parseFloat($("#f_content_credit").text()).toFixed(2);
  var total_balance = parseFloat($("#f_total_balance").text()).toFixed(2);
  var tip = parseFloat(thiz.val()).toFixed(2);
  var final = (total_balance - content_credit - tip).toFixed(2);

  console.log(final);
  $("#f_after_confirm").text(final);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <strong>Total Balance</strong> 
      </td>
      <td id='f_total_balance'>45.67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <strong>Credit</strong> 
      </td>
      <td id='f_content_credit'>10.20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <strong>TIP BOX</strong>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="tip" class='form-control'>
          <option value="0" selected>0 Kredi</option>
          <option value="0.10">0.1 credit</option>
          <option value="0.20">0.2 credit | works now</option>
          <option value="0.30">0.3 credit</option>
          <option value="0.80">0.8 credit</option>
          <option value="1.20">1.2 credit | works now</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <strong>After Confirm Calculation</strong> 
        <br><small>Total Balance - Credit - Tip</small> 
      </td>
      <td id='f_after_confirm'>35.47</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use with `Math.round(100 * tot) / 100;` Its will fixed with `.12` digits

```js
$("select[name='tip']").on('change',function(){
    var thiz = $(this);
    var content_credit = parseFloat($("#f_content_credit").text());
    var total_balance = parseFloat($("#f_total_balance").text());
    var tip = parseFloat(thiz.val());
  var tot = total_balance-content_credit-tip;
var cal = Math.round(100 * tot) / 100;
    console.log(cal);
    
    $("#f_after_confirm").text(cal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
            <td> <strong>Total Balance</strong> </td>
            <td id='f_total_balance'> 45.67 </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
            <td> <strong>Credit</strong> </td>
            <td id='f_content_credit'> 10.20 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <strong>TIP BOX</strong></td>
            <td> 
                <select name="tip" class='form-control'>
                    <option value="0" selected>0 Kredi</option>
                    <option value="0.10">0.1 credit</option>
                    <option value="0.20">0.2 credit | not working</option>
                    <option value="0.30">0.3 credit</option>
                    <option value="0.80">0.8 credit</option>
                    <option value="1.20">1.2 credit | not working</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <strong>After Confirm Calculation</strong> <br><small>Total Balance - Credit - Tip</small> </td>
            <td id='f_after_confirm'> 35.47 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```